# using "new" on a class not showing objects

Tags: c#, object

The title may have been confusing, but the problem is too...

I am trying to create a 'new' of the class 'Level' that is called 'Aquamarine.'
Is there a way to make the strings and integers shown for 'Level.*' appear for 'Aquamarine.*'?

Class: meowvaCoreLibraries

```
public static void setDefaultLevelsFlaciea()
    {
        //Level Aquamarine
        Level Aquamarine = new Level();

    }
```

Class: Level

```
public static string name;//These dont appear under Aquamarine.*
    public static string republicName;//same

    public static int ID;//same
    public static int entryPoints;//same

    public static void connectToUser(string username) {
    //only these do
    }
    public static void displayMessageInfo()
    {
        if (name != string.Empty && republicName != string.Empty && ID != null && entryPoints != null)
        {
            geoMainModules.messageBasic("Level " + name, "Level " + name + " of the " + republicName + " requires " 
                + entryPoints + " points and has an ID of " + ID + ".");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn what `static` means.

Comment: You dont instantiate static classes, they follow a singleton pattern. So you just call methods on the static class (without having any instances), eg: `Level.displayMessageInfo();`

Comment: To the downvoters, while this question does show a painful lack of knowledge around the mechanics of static, it is a good question in accordance with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and does not deserve a blind downvote.

Comment: @DavidL Even ignoring all that, he could still mean various things and it's unclear what he's actually trying to do. At least to me, it is.

Comment: @YoryeNathan He's trying access static methods from an instance rather than the class directly. If his class was abstract (which it looks like it should be) he quite possibly would have avoided the issue.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Oh okay, "showing objects" as in showing intellisense and compiling, now I get it.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Drew described my understanding as well, which is why it seemed to be a perfectly reasonable and valid question to me.

Comment: @DavidL Indeed a legit question, I retracted my close vote (I usually don't down-vote questions which I suggest closing, since I don't see the point)

Answer (score 1):

You dont instantiate static classes, they follow a singleton pattern.

You call methods on the static class (without having any instances), eg:

```
public static void setDefaultLevelsFlaciea()
{
    //Wrong (you cant instantiate a static class)
    //Level Aquamarine = new Level();

    //Right
    Level.displayMessageInfo();
}
```

I think the solution for you is to make the Level class' fields and methods non-static. To do that simply delete all the *static* keywords from the Level class.